# Why Plot does not work with a computed integral?

Tags: plotting

I have been following the examples of the official W|A documentation; exactly:

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UsingANotebookInterface.html

The `Plot` command generates the x and axes, but it does not show the corrersponding plot:

See this screenshot:

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Isn't the value of the function -Infinity at 1 and an imaginary number at 2?

Comment: I think you found a bizarre error (or two) in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

```
f[x_] = Integrate[1/(x^3 - 1), x]
```

> -(ArcTan[(1 + 2 x)/Sqrt[3]]/Sqrt[3]) + 1/3 Log[1 - x] - 1/6 Log[1 + x + x^2]

If you look at some values of the function you will see that it is complex. You must plot a real-valued function.

```
Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, 1., 2., .25}]
```

> {{1., Indeterminate}, {1.25, -1.32673 + 1.0472 I}, {1.5, -1.16171 + 
>      1.0472 I}, {1.75, -1.084 + 1.0472 I}, {2., -1.03869 + 1.0472 I}}

```
Plot[{Re[f[x]], Im[f[x]], Abs[f[x]]}, {x, 1, 2},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Comment: Really interesting would be an idea what was the version of the system evaluating here [Examples of Integrals](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UsingANotebookInterface.html)

Comment: @Artes - It is not a version issue but rather an error in the documentation. The graph in the documentation show the x axis from 0 to 1 even though the `Plot` is supposed to be from 1 to 2.

Comment: Indeed, however neither this works as they claimed: `Integrate[1/(x^3 - 1), x]` then `Plot[%, {x, 0, 1}]` yields something different.

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at `Plot`:

[image]

If you specify *xmin* and *xmax*, the function f is calculated with these values ​​and plotted. Actually, you plug xmin and xmax in the function f and get the corresponding result.The plot corresponds to your specifications.

The integral is given the name f:

```
f = ∫1/(x^3 - 1) \[DifferentialD]x
(*
-(ArcTan[(1 + 2 x)/Sqrt[3]]/Sqrt[3]) + 1/3 Log[1 - x] - 1/6 Log[1 + x + x^2]
*)
```

If we generate some plots with different xmin and xmax we can represent the behavior of *xmin* and *xmax* like so:

```
po0 = Plot[f, {x, 1, 2}];
po1 = Plot[f, {x, -1, 1}];
po2 = Plot[f, {x, -5, 5}];
po3 = Plot[f, {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> All];
```

[image]

This means: a plot of *f* as a function of *x* from *xmin* to *xmax* is not equal to the [PlotRange](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html).

You can check `FunctionDomain` and `FunctionRange` with:

```
{FunctionDomain[f, x], FunctionRange[f, x, y]}
```

$\left\{x<1,y<\frac{\pi }{2 \sqrt{3}}\right\}$

To check if expression contains a complex expression you can use:

```
FreeQ[f, _Complex]
(*
True
*)
```

or

```
FunctionDomain[f, x, Complexes]
```

$(x-1) \left(2 \sqrt{3} x-3 i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(2 \sqrt{3} x+3 i+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(x^2+x+1\right)\neq 0$

And now we can plot the function *f* with real part, imaginary part and absolute value:

```
Plot[{Re[f], Im[f], Abs[f]}, {x, -4, 4}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]